# como resolvo problema de desempenho no useEffect no react native?

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

Boa noite, estou fazendo duas requisições a uma API do TMDB porem estou com um problema de desempneho quadno armazeno na variavel, ele até funciona, porem fica muito lento e impossivel de usar, estou começando e não sei como arrumar, poderiam me ajudar ?

PS(Estou escondendo as chaves por motivo de segurança)

`   const [filmes, setFilmes] = useState([])
const [series, setSeries] = useState([])

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function carregarDadosMovie(){
        const respostaMovie: any = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=************************')
        setFilmes(respostaMovie.data.results)
    }            
    carregarDadosMovie()
})
useEffect(() => {
    async function carregarDadosSerie(){
        const respostaSerie: any = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/tv/week?api_key=***************************')
        setSeries(respostaSerie.data.results)
    }
    carregarDadosSerie()
})`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da maneira que você está fazendo, o *callback* passado para a função `useEffect` será executado toda vez que o estado do seu componente mudar.

Ele está caindo num loop infinito, em que ao rodar o callback, você usa o `setFilmes` ou o `setSeries`, forçando o callback rodar novamente.

Para esses casos você precisa passar um array de estados para a função `useEffect`, contendo todos os estados em que quando alterados, devem fazer a função rodar novamente. Como essas funções só precisam rodar uma vez ao iniciar o componente, e não precisam rodar novamente quando o estado é alterado, passe um array vazio:

```
const [filmes, setFilmes] = useState([])
const [series, setSeries] = useState([])

useEffect(async () => {
    const respostaMovie: any = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week?api_key=************************')
    setFilmes(respostaMovie.data.results)
}, [])

useEffect(async () => {
    const respostaSerie: any = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/tv/week?api_key=***************************')
    setSeries(respostaSerie.data.results)
}, [])
```

Comment: Boa tarde Andre, testei aqui e funcionou certinho, comecei a aprender a pouco tempo e me ajudou muito, muito obrigado.